# how to setup cross realm trust between two instances of freeIPA

Tags: trust, freeipa

I have a need to setup cross realm trust between to freeIPA instances. I see documentation for setting up trust between freeIPA and AD but not to set it up between two freeIPA instances.

I am using the version: VERSION: 4.6.6, API_VERSION: 2.231

Is the trust setup between two freeipa servers available in above version ?

Answer (score 0):

A trust between IPA deployments is currently not supported.

Answer (score 0):

trust between 2 and more realms is not supported but it is possible if to fork community code with a trust sssd plugin or to change trust class.
If it is legit so you can do it easy by couple of strings if you have good skill in C and python of course.